# MySQL data can not be updated

Tags: php, mysql

i have a little problem here. No error notice showing, but the data is not inserted / updated into database. Can anybody tell me why?

Here is my code:

```
$perbandingan = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ar_produk_detail WHERE id_produk = '$_GET[id]'");
    $rows = mysql_num_rows($perbandingan);
    while($w = mysql_fetch_array($perbandingan)){
        $w_id[] = $w['id_subkategori'];
        $p_id[] = $w['id_produk_det'];
    }

    $data = $_POST['checkbox'];
    $sum = count($data);

    for ($r = 0; $r < $sum; $r++){
            if($w_id[$r] != $data[$r]){
                $do = "UPDATE FROM ar_produk_detail SET id_subkategori = '".$data[$r]."' WHERE id_produk_det = '".$p_id[$r]."'";
                mysql_query($do); //Hapus yang tidak sama / tidak terpilih
                echo $do;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `$p_id[$r]` should be `$w_id[$r]`, no?

Comment: Check for the result of mysql_query, if it is `false` an error occured. Also switch to `mysqli` or `PDO`

Comment: echo $do and run query on phpmyadmin

Comment: FROM should be the name of the table and there shouldn't be apostrophes around the id variables.

Comment: my bad, code has edited.

Comment: FROM should still be the name of the table. FROM isn't used in the  UPDATE-statement.

Answer (score 2):

It should not be

```
UPDATE FROM ar_produk_detail SET id_subkateg
```

But

```
"UPDATE  ar_produk_detail SET id_subkateg = '".$data[$r]."' WHERE id_produk_det = '".$p_id[$r]."'";
```

You do not need FROM  in UPDATE query.

Comment: ah damn, thank you very much.. i think my brain was not connected with my hand.. hahaha

Answer (score 2):

```
$perbandingan = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ar_produk_detail WHERE id_produk = '$_GET[id]'");
    $rows = mysql_num_rows($perbandingan);
    while($w = mysql_fetch_array($perbandingan)){
        $w_id[] = $w['id_subkategori'];
        $p_id[] = $w['id_produk_det'];
    }

    $data = $_POST['checkbox'];
    $sum = count($data);

    for ($r = 0; $r < $sum; $r++){
            if($w_id[$r] != $data[$r]){
                $do = mysql_query("UPDATE  ar_produk_detail SET id_subkateg = '$data[$r]' WHERE id_produk_det = '$p_id[$r]'");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $do = "UPDATE ar_produk_detail SET id_subkategori = '".$data[$r]."' WHERE id_produk_det = '".$p_id[$r]."'";

// Remove from in  the query
```

Comment: You should try to add explanations to your answers, not just post code. Now the author has to take his code, your code and do a comparison to find out what he did wrong. SO is not about fixing code, but about helping people to help themselves. Please consider this and have fun on SO. :)

Answer (score 0):

$do = "UPDATE FROM ar_produk_detail SET id_subkategori = '".$data[$r]."' WHERE id_produk_det = '".$p_id[$r]."'";

Look in update query you using "FORM", that is incorrect.

correct syntax
UPDATE table_name SET column1=value1 WHERE some_column=some_value;

so you must remove "FROM" from your query
 $do = "UPDATE ar_produk_detail SET id_subkategori = '".$data[$r]."' WHERE id_produk_det = '".$p_id[$r]."'";